# How to rotate according to face normal?

Tags: normals, 3d-cursor, origin

I want to place cursor with copying face rotation (Normal?)

[image: Place Cursor to face]

First I place cursor to where door handle will be placed

[image]

Then create a circle object where cursor is placed.

[image]

I want to rotate my circle according to face rotation(Normal?). Is that possible?

Comment: select the face and in the Transform Orientations panel, you can create a custom orientation (click on the "+" button)

Comment: @moonboots I can`t find where is '+' button

Answer (score 1):

Select the face and in the *Transform Orientations* panel, click on the "+" button in order to create a custom orientation:

[image]